# Trying to print specific values from a column .csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get and print all the values (integers) from a column  that matches with an specific input. The lenght of the input must be between 3 and 15, as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", engine='python', sep=';')

def codechoice(): 
 codeNum = int(input("What's the code: "))
 if (len(str(codeNum))) > 3 and (len(str(codeNum))) < 15:
      result = file[file['Column 2'].str.contains(codeNum)]
      print(result)

codechoice()
```

It's showing the result as expected, but also it's showing all other columns from the csv file of that specific input.
Also, if I input, lets say, "100", it is printing all the ocurrencies that has "100" in its length.

The question is:
How do I delimit that I want only one specific Column?

Example, if entering the input I just wanted to print the columns 4 and 5?
And how to correct the length error?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I added some coding to present with some example data so you might need to tweek it a little to match your own data set, but this will return all the rows that match a zip_code that you enter as a df

```
data = {
    'State' : ['NC', 'SC', 'NC', 'SC'],
    'ZipCode' : [28215, 10101, 28201, 10111]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def codechoice(): 
    codeNum = int(input("What's the code: "))
    if (len(str(codeNum))) > 3 and (len(str(codeNum))) < 15:
        result = df.loc[df['ZipCode'] == int(codeNum)]
        return result

zip_choice_df = codechoice()
zip_choice_df
```

From there if you wanted to only limit the return to a specific set of columns you can take another step by adding a df = df[[]] to limit to the specific columns like so:

```
data = {
    'State' : ['NC', 'SC', 'NC', 'SC'],
    'Country' : ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
    'ZipCode' : [28215, 10101, 28201, 10111]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def codechoice(): 
    codeNum = int(input("What's the code: "))
    if (len(str(codeNum))) > 3 and (len(str(codeNum))) < 15:
        result = df.loc[df['ZipCode'] == int(codeNum)]
        return result

zip_choice_df = codechoice()
zip_choice_df = zip_choice_df[['State', 'Country']]
zip_choice_df
```

Comment: Hi. The csv file has more than 30.000 rows and 50 columns, I still haven't figured out a way to transform it in a dataframe. How would you do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then. The second set of code should return a specific set of columns (that you can specify in my example it was State and Country) and it comes back as a dataframe. If this isn't what you wanted please put some screenshots or programable results in your post for further review

Comment: Im new into csv manipulation so excuse for any misunderstanding. Basically, my "data" (in your code) is the "file" (in my code)? Tried to do the first method, so I defined df = pd.DataFrame(file) and continued... "result = df.loc[df['ZipCode'] == int(codeNum)]" it returns this: "Empty DataFrame" and then rolls out every 50 column names. No results

Comment: Yes my code is an example of what would be your file. So what you would want to do to get the df from my code using a file would be (if it is a csv) `df = pd.read_csv(file location)` from there the code should work the same

Comment: I'm getting Empty DataFrame" and then rolls out every 50 column names. No results. Any idea whats going wrong? my code: https://ibb.co/Nrs1VZ0